# i cannot use my sql connector jar file although i have added the jar file in vs code referenced libary

Tags: java, jar, driver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTjFA.png)I have already added the jar file in vs code but it is showing package com mySql jdbc does not exist

I have tried all the way of adding jar file in vs code added jar file in referenced libraies also in lib folder but did not worked

code :

import java.sql.*;public class java01{

```
public static void main(String[] args) { try{
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1dBn.png)
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());

```
} catch (Exception e){
e.getStackTrace();
}

}}
```

Comment: Please don't post code images or bugs if possible, copy your code or code error into question with block code format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTjFA.png) you shared I pressume you do not have "MySQL connector jar" in your `classpath` when you compile/run this program.

So when you try to compile it

```bash
javac ./*.java
```

you gonna get an error

```bash
./Main.java:9: error: package com.mysql.jdbc does not exist
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
                                                       ^
1 error
```

The solution for this is to include "MySQL connector jar" into your `classpath`

```bash
javac -cp ~/.m2/repository/com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/8.0.32/mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar ./*.java
```